# Physical type Click for Webbrowser website combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I am working on a project to enter data in website from windows form with programming. I am headed with a issue related to combobox Physical mouse/keyboard click event.

from 3 days i am googling for solution and tested multiple combinations, but no success.

**Project:** My windows form project has a webbrowser controller and it loads a remote website in it. The website has 2 combobox on it. first had the default options value in it, but initially nothing selected. Second combobox data is dependent on the first combobox selected value. Initial second combobox has no data in it, once user click mouse/keyboard on a value of First combobox then second combobox load data in it (from server/xml/java).

**Issue:** I am successfully able to set the value of First combobox with code. but i need a physical mouse/keyboard type click on First combobox to get the value for second combobox. Second combobox value is dependable on first combobox, and initially second combobox has no value in it.

**My Work:**
This is website code (demo i created for testing locally).

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

         ////////////////////////////////
        $("#myselectbox").change(function () {
            if ($("#myselectbox option:selected").attr("value") == "saab") {
                var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
                var option = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    option += '<option value="' + numbers[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>';
                }
                $('#myselectbox2').append(option);`enter code here`
            }                
        });
        ///////////////////////////////////

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {    
        margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;

     }
</style>
<body>
<select id="myselectbox">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="myselectbox2">
</select>
</body>
```

C# code

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/myHTML/mainPage.html", curDir));
```

TEST1: This code works to set the value of first combobox, and changes are visible in website, but it not trigger the click on it like mouse/keyboard. RESULT: second combobox no value.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myselectbox").SetAttribute("value", "saab");
}
```

TEST2: same results as TEST1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");


        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {

            if (element.GetAttribute("id") == "myselectbox")
            {
                element.GetElementsByTagName("option")[1].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");

                //webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myselectbox").InvokeMember("Click");
                //webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack");
                //webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myselectbox").RaiseEvent("onChange");

            }
        }


    }
```

TEST3: same results as TEST1

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");

}
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myselectbox").Focus();

    }
```

TEST4: no luck

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
        {
            if (el.Id == "myselectbox")
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement comboItem in el.Children)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(comboItem.InnerText + " " + comboItem.GetAttribute("Selected"));
                    if (comboItem.InnerText == "Saab")
                    {
                        comboItem.SetAttribute("selected", "true");
                        //            SendKeys.Send("\t");
                        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
}
```

TEST5: I can see the debug result as the event finds the element but no click trigger. I was expecting result that might be First combobox will open for options and i might be able to use sendkeys.send tab to values. but no luck

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point k = new Point(2,30);
        HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(k);
        ele.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

[image: Result in debug]

Note: I do not know much  info how/where second combobox getting the data. i was testing on the live website with firebug tool, then it found that second combobox data comes from a xml file from server. *I dnt want to go in this direction to get the data for second combobox*, because that xml link triggers after i click first combobox physically with mouse.

Note: In future webbrowser controller will be hidden from the windows form.

**Any kind of suggestion/code/link will be highly appreciable, many thanks in advance** :)

Comment: Why dont you use Selenium?

Comment: hi, not allowed to user 3rd party software in this project. End user want transparency in coding.